# ImageIcon height and width getting -1,how to get image width and height in java?

Tags: java, image-processing, image-resizing, imageresizer-diskcache

Here i'm getting image name from file i.e., galaxy.png and im able to get galaxy.png in icon object when i print icon height and with its giving -1 rather than its original width and height?

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(fileName);
out.println(icon.getIconHeight() + "" + icon.getIconWidth());
```

Could anybody help me to solve this problem.

Comment: There are at least two reasons this might fail. 1- The image couldn't be found and wasn't load or 2: The image was found and hasn't yet been loaded.  Consider using `ImageIO.read` instead to test which case this is...

Comment: @mre Im not storing image in system drive ,when i choose image at that time getting image from choosen path so here i used ImageIcon,but when BuffredImage is used to read stored image that is not my issue.

Comment: @MadProgrammer,I'm not Storing Image in sytem drive ,when we save at that time only we use ImageIO.read

Comment: So what is `fileName`?  `ImageIcon` does not load the image immediately, it offloads the image loading to another thread, which means that when you inspect the properties of the image it might not have enough information available...

Comment: @MadProgrammer,String imgName = item.getName();
String fileName = new File(imgName).getName();   where item.getName means galaxy.png when i select image using formField im just getting name.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, if you dont mind can you tell me your email id ,i will forward my code

Comment: @MadProgrammer,could you please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/24643958/3467244  here is my full code,please help me solve this issue.

Comment: `ImageIcon(String)` expects the path/file of the image you want to load.  You seem to be only passing the name of the file...how is Java suppose to know how to associate some "name" to all the files on the file system.  It would be better to pass it `uploadedFile.getPath()`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56988/discussion-between-thaz-ahammad-and-madprogrammer).